# Difficulty in maintaining the previous state of progress bar when activity is resumed

Tags: android

I am trying to download an mp3 file. For this i have created an activity like this:

```
public class audiostream extends Activity{

private Button streamButton;

private ImageButton playButton;

private TextView textStreamed;

private boolean isPlaying;

private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer; //This is the object of supporting class

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //other activities                     }
```

now on the button click event i am calling this function:

```
private void startStreamingAudio() {
        try { 
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            if ( audioStreamer != null) {
                audioStreamer.interrupt();
            }
            audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this,textStreamed, playButton, streamButton,progressBar);
            audioStreamer.startStreaming("file path",file_size,duration);

            streamButton.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }
```

Give below is the StreamingMediaPlayer class:

```
public class StreamingMediaPlayer {


    private TextView textStreamed;

    private ImageButton playButton;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context,TextView textStreamed, ImageButton playButton, Button  streamButton,ProgressBar    progressBar) 
        {
        this.context = context;
        this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
        this.playButton = playButton;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
       }

}
```

Rest of the works are done by the remaining class such as incrementing the progress bar, playing the audio etc.

Progress bar increments as audio progresses. The issue that i am facing is that, while playing the audio, if i am pressing back button and opening previous activity the audio plays (this is what i want), but when i come back to the activity with the help of intent, everything appears in a way that activity is just created. The progress bar which was previously progressing now looks when i first opened this activity. In simple sentence the problem is that, the activity which is playing the audio file is not resuming the previous state. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `onCreate(savedInstance)` is precisely designed to save the state of an activity. See [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Answer (score 0):

in the activity-lifecycle you have to catch the onResume() Intent and fill your data accordingly.

Comment: As the main control is with another class, i am exactly not sure how to bring back the previous state of control in the onResume()